# Memory leak tf.data + Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a memory leak in  my training pipeline and don't know how to fix it.

I use Tensorflow version: 1.9.0 and Keras (tf) version: 2.1.6-tf with Python 3.5.2

This is how my training pipeline looks like:

```
for i in range(num_epochs):

    training_data = training_set.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    hist = model.fit(training_data[0],[training_data[1],training_data[2],training_data[3]],
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_train,epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=[history, MemoryCallback()])


    # custom validation
```

It looks like memory of the iterator is not freed after the iterator is exhausted. I have already tried `del traininig_data` after `model.fit`. It didn't work.

Can anybody give some hints?

Edit: 
This is how I create the dataset.

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_filename)
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=preprocess_fn, num_parallel_calls=8)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(100)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
```

Comment: Are you caching the dataset (trainin_set)?

Comment: No, I don't cache the dataset. Would it help?

Comment: Caching might explain that the dataset is still in memory. How do you build the dataset?

Comment: I made an edit to my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow runs out of memory while computing: how to find memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175837/tensorflow-runs-out-of-memory-while-computing-how-to-find-memory-leaks)

Comment: Thanks. The issue is similar. I think I am constantly adding nodes to the graph with the make_one_shot_iterator operation. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Including the [repeat()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) method to reinitialize your iterator might solve your problem. You can take a look at [Input Pipeline Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance#summary_of_best_practices) to figure out what would be the a good optimized order of your methods according to your requirements.

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(100)
dataset = dataset.repeat() # Can specify num_epochs as input if needed
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
```

In case you can afford to do the validation as a part of the fit method, you can use something like the code below and lose the loop altogether to make your life easier.

```
training_data = training_set.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
# val_data refers to your validation data and steps_per_epochs_val refers to no of your validation batches
hist = model.fit(training_data[0],training_data[1],training_data[2],training_data[3]], validation_data=val_data.make_one_shot_iterator(), validation_steps=steps_per_epochs_val, 
       steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_train, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[history, MemoryCallback()])
```

Reference: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_dataset_api.py