# Keras predict loop memory leak using tf.data.Dataset but not with a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I encounter a memory leak and decreasing performance when looping over a Keras model `predict` function when using a `tf.data.Dataset` to feed the model, but not when feeding it with a numpy array.

Does anyone understand what is causing this and/or how to resolve the issue?

**Minimal reproducible code snippet (copy/paste runnable):**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

SIZE = 5000

inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(SIZE,), dtype='float32')
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=SIZE)(inp)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)

np_data = np.random.rand(1, SIZE)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_data).batch(1).repeat()

debug_time = time.time()
while True:
    model.predict(x=ds, steps=1)
    print('Processing {:.2f}'.format(time.time() - debug_time))
    debug_time = time.time()
```

**Result:** Predict loop timing starts around 0.04s per iteration, within a minute or two it's up to about 0.5s and process memory continues to increase from a few hundred MB to close to a GB.

---

Swap out the `tf.data.Dataset` for an equivalent numpy array and runtime is ~0.01s consistently.

**Working case code snippet (copy/paste runnable):**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

SIZE = 5000

inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(SIZE,), dtype='float32')
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=SIZE)(inp)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)

np_data = np.random.rand(1, SIZE)

debug_time = time.time()
while True:
    model.predict(x=np_data)  # using numpy array directly
    print('Processing {:.2f}'.format(time.time() - debug_time))
    debug_time = time.time()
```

---

Related discussions:

- [Memory leak tf.data + Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493849/memory-leak-tf-data-keras) - Doesn't seem to address the core issue, but the question appears similar.
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22098 - Possibly an open issue in Keras/Github, but I can't confirm it, changing `inter_op_paralellism` as suggested in that thread has no impact on the results posted here.

---

Additional info:

- I can reduce the rate of performance degradation by around 10x by passing in an iterator instead of a dataset object. I noticed in `training_utils.py:1314` the Keras code is creating an iterator each call to predict.

TF 1.14.0

Comment: What’s your question? Would you like an explanation of why this phenomena occurs? Please clarify in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem appears to be that Keras is creating dataset operations each `predict` loop. Notice at `training_utils.py:1314` a dataset iterator is created in each predict loop.

The problem can be reduced in severity by passing in an iterator, and is solved entirely by passing in the iterators `get_next()` tensor.

I have posted the issue on the Tensorflow Github page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30448

Here is the solution, this example runs in constant time using the TF dataset, you just can't pass in the dataset object:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

SIZE = 5000

inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(SIZE,), dtype='float32')
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=SIZE)(inp)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)

np_data = np.random.rand(1, SIZE)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_data).batch(1).repeat()
it = tf.data.make_one_shot_iterator(ds)
tensor = it.get_next()

debug_time = time.time()
while True:
    model.predict(x=tensor, steps=1)
    print('Processing {:.2f}'.format(time.time() - debug_time))
    debug_time = time.time()
```